# border-style:dotted is not working in firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

`border-style:dotted` is not working in firefox

I have read in [Here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_border-style.asp) other than property `hidden` in IE all the properties support is all browser.

But with my code `border-style:dotted` is not working but if I will give `border-style:solid` it is working. (if i will just change `border-style:solid` it will work fine ?? but why?)
Can any explain me why it is happening ?

[See Here](http://jsfiddle.net/tb48r/3/) 
Please try to run [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tb48r/3/) in `chrome` and `firefox`.

Thanks !!

Comment: I don't think it's the `border-style` property that's giving you trouble - it is something else in your code. [View this in FF and Chrome](http://jsfiddle.net/tb48r/6/)

Comment: Why have you assigned hieght 0 and width 0 , chaning them gives something like this http://jsfiddle.net/tb48r/7/ . is this what you want ?

Comment: @Mustafasabir I followed this http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/ for creating triangles..

Comment: firefox has a different behavior(bug) with dotted and dashed borders, we mostly see this difference when  border-radius is applied. https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=382721 your fiddle with colors: http://jsfiddle.net/tb48r/8/

Comment: @GCyrillus It seems you are correct. Can you please tell me if border-style property is not giving trouble, what's the issue ?? –

Comment: It seems to be that mozilla has not find a way to have dotted and dashed borders on corners being drawn correctly,  this is unfortunately an old bug . somehow, i would say, that using dotted or dashed style to end up drawing a triangle is not coherent , nor the best style option :)

Answer (score 1):

CSS triangles relies on the border property to render it as a triangle, making it dotted or solid does not matter in the rendering and does therefor not show the border as "dotted" - if you try it on the fiddle you can see changing the color on the border actually changes the entire triangle.

Triangles: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/

Comment: can you please tell me if border-style property is not giving trouble, what's the issue ??

Comment: I am sorry that I can't really give a correct answer, what I am saying is I don't think you can specifically give CSS triangles a border since they rely on the border property itself to become a triangle.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this syntax:

```
element {
border: [thickness]px [type] [color];
}
```

Example:

```
body {
border: 10px solid black;
}
--
body {
border: 20px dotted black;
}
--
body {
border: 30px dashed black;
}
--
body {
border: 40px groove black;
}
```

**UPDATE:**

Upon your query, this IS NOT WORKING AND WILL NOT WORK because,

=> You are already applying border as background. If you look closely, border style dotted is stretched to form background as you are using border width property. Don't judge it as background color. You cannot apply border on a border.
=> To make it work, either introduce another pseudo or actual element and make it do that what you wanted to do.

Comment: see if i will just change border-style:solid it will work fine ?? but why?